# Value being lost in functions process

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up the TweetieJS script, but for some reason I'm running in to errors. After doing some digging it appears that the value of `e` is getting wiped at this point meaning it then throws up errors when needed.

The first `console.log` outputs `ƒ (a,b){return new r.fn.init(a,b)}` but the second one is just empty. Using `n.empty(), e.forEach(function(e) {` throws an error:

> e.forEach is not a function

The `n.empty(), Array.from(e).forEach(function(e) {` line just doesn't return anything.

If I add `var x = e;` just after the first console log, then add `var e = x;` just before the second console log, the script moves on, but `e` is referenced multiple times after.

```js
console.log(e);

e.get(a.url, {
  type: a.type,
  params: a.params
}).done(function(e) {
  var t = a.template,
    o = a.dateFormat;

  console.log(e);

  n.empty(), Array.from(e).forEach(function(e) {
    //n.empty(), e.forEach(function(e) {
    var r = (0, u.default)(e, t, o);
    n.append(r)
  }), "function" == typeof r && r()
}).fail(function(t) {
  if (t.responseJSON) {
    var n = t.responseJSON.errors;
    n && (n.forEach(function(t) {
      return e.error(t.message)
    }), "function" == typeof r && r(n))
  } else e.error(t), "function" == typeof r && r(t)
})
```

Comment: inside callback e will not be an array, so forEach is not applicable

Comment: @DickensAS so re-assign each variable inside each callback?